# Channel bonding modes

Tags: networking, documentation, network-bonding

I wanted to know where is the documentation of channel bonding implementation in Ubuntu because the bonding modes are described differently on the internet

I have Ubuntu Server 10.0.4 LTS and it's using 2.6 kernel

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu documentation related to bonding modes is available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding).

Descriptions of Ethernet bonding modes:

### Mode 0

```
balance-rr
```

Round-robin policy: Transmit packets in sequential order from the first available slave through the last. This mode provides load balancing and fault tolerance.

### Mode 1

```
active-backup
```

Active-backup policy: Only one slave in the bond is active. A different slave becomes active if, and only if, the active slave fails. The bond's MAC address is externally visible on only one port (network adapter) to avoid confusing the switch. This mode provides fault tolerance. The primary option affects the behavior of this mode.

### Mode 2

```
balance-xor
```

XOR policy: Transmit based on [(source MAC address XOR'd with destination MAC address) modulo slave count]. This selects the same slave for each destination MAC address. This mode provides load balancing and fault tolerance.

### Mode 3

```
broadcast
```

Broadcast policy: transmits everything on all slave interfaces. This mode provides fault tolerance.

### Mode 4

```
802.3ad
```

IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation. Creates aggregation groups that share the same speed and duplex settings. Utilizes all slaves in the active aggregator according to the 802.3ad specification.

Prerequisites:

- Ethtool support in the base drivers for retrieving the speed and duplex of each slave.
- A switch that supports IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation. Most switches will require some type of configuration to enable 802.3ad mode.

### Mode 5

```
balance-tlb
```

Adaptive transmit load balancing: channel bonding that does not require any special switch support. The outgoing traffic is distributed according to the current load (computed relative to the speed) on each slave. Incoming traffic is received by the current slave. If the receiving slave fails, another slave takes over the MAC address of the failed receiving slave.

Prerequisites:

- Ethtool support in the base drivers for retrieving the speed of each slave.

### Mode 6

```
balance-alb
```

Adaptive load balancing: includes balance-tlb plus receive load balancing (rlb) for IPV4 traffic, and does not require any special switch support. The receive load balancing is achieved by ARP negotiation. The bonding driver intercepts the ARP Replies sent by the local system on their way out and overwrites the source hardware address with the unique hardware address of one of the slaves in the bond such that different peers use different hardware addresses for the server.

Comment: Thank you I already found this but it's not enough. I need something saying how each mode work in a much more specific way.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best source is this [Kernel.org document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt), it also provides explanations about when is each type optimal, and so on.

The sections are long, I only paste short excerpts:

> ### 11.2.1 HA Bonding Mode Selection for Multiple Switch Topology
>
> In a topology such as the example above, the active-backup and
>   broadcast modes are the only useful bonding modes when optimizing for
>   availability; the other modes require all links to terminate on the
>   same peer for them to behave rationally.
>
> active-backup: This is generally the preferred mode, particularly if
>     the switches have an ISL and play together well.  If the    network
>   configuration is such that one switch is specifically     a backup switch
>   (e.g., has lower capacity, higher cost, etc),     then the primary option
>   can be used to insure that the    preferred link is always used when it
>   is available.
>
> broadcast: This mode is really a special purpose mode, and is suitable
>     only for very specific needs.  For example, if the two  switches are
>   not connected (no ISL), and the networks beyond   them are totally
>   independent.  In this case, if it is  necessary for some specific
>   one-way traffic to reach both     independent networks, then the
>   broadcast mode may be suitable.
>
> ...
>
> ### 12.1.1 MT Bonding Mode Selection for Single Switch Topology
>
> This configuration is the easiest to set up and to understand,
>   although you will have to decide which bonding mode best suits your
>   needs.  The trade offs for each mode are detailed below:
>
> balance-rr: This mode is the only mode that will permit a single
>     TCP/IP connection to stripe traffic across multiple     interfaces. It
>   is therefore the only mode that will allow a  single TCP/IP stream to
>   utilize more than one interface's     worth of throughput.  This comes at
>   a cost, however: the  striping generally results in peer systems
>   receiving packets out     of order, causing TCP/IP's congestion control
>   system to kick    in, often by retransmitting segments.
>
> ...
>
> active-backup: There is not much advantage in this network topology to
>     the active-backup mode, as the inactive backup devices are all
>     connected to the same peer as the primary.  In this case, a     load
>   balancing mode (with link monitoring) will provide the    same level of
>   network availability, but with increased  available bandwidth.  On the
>   plus side, active-backup mode     does not require any configuration of
>   the switch, so it may     have value if the hardware available does not
>   support any of    the load balance modes.
>
> balance-xor: This mode will limit traffic such that packets destined
>     for specific peers will always be sent over the same    interface. 
>   Since the destination is determined by the MAC    addresses involved,
>   this mode works best in a "local" network     configuration (as described
>   above), with destinations all on  the same local network.  This mode
>   is likely to be suboptimal    if all your traffic is passed through a
>   single router (i.e., a    "gatewayed" network configuration, as
>   described above).
>
> As with balance-rr, the switch ports need to be configured for
>     "etherchannel" or "trunking."
>
> broadcast: Like active-backup, there is not much advantage to this
>     mode in this type of network topology.
>
> 802.3ad: This mode can be a good choice for this type of network  topology.  The 802.3ad mode is an IEEE standard, so all peers   that
>   implement 802.3ad should interoperate well.  The 802.3ad  protocol
>   includes automatic configuration of the aggregates,   so minimal manual
>   configuration of the switch is needed     (typically only to designate
>   that some set of devices is   available for 802.3ad).  The 802.3ad
>   standard also mandates    that frames be delivered in order (within
>   certain limits), so   in general single connections will not see
>   misordering of    packets.  The 802.3ad mode does have some drawbacks:
>   the   standard mandates that all devices in the aggregate operate at
>     the same speed and duplex.  Also, as with all bonding load  balance
>   modes other than balance-rr, no single connection will    be able to
>   utilize more than a single interface's worth of   bandwidth.
>
> ...
>
> balance-tlb: The balance-tlb mode balances outgoing traffic by peer.
>     Since the balancing is done according to MAC address, in a
>     "gatewayed" configuration (as described above), this mode will  send
>   all traffic across a single device.  However, in a    "local" network
>   configuration, this mode balances multiple    local network peers across
>   devices in a vaguely intelligent  manner (not a simple XOR as in
>   balance-xor or 802.3ad mode),     so that mathematically unlucky MAC
>   addresses (i.e., ones that    XOR to the same value) will not all "bunch
>   up" on a single   interface.
>
> ...
>
> balance-alb: This mode is everything that balance-tlb is, and more.
>     It has all of the features (and restrictions) of balance-tlb,   and
>   will also balance incoming traffic from local network     peers (as
>   described in the Bonding Module Options section,  above).
>
> The only additional down side to this mode is that the network
>     device driver must support changing the hardware address while  the
>   device is open.